# Are comments of people (desperately) asking for people to consider accepting their answer to earn reputation discouraged?

Tags: discussion, comments

While looking around old posts on A&M, I've encountered my fair share of comments asking for the OP of the said question to consider accepting their answer. Comments like:

- Hi, @(op's username) please upvote this answer if it helped you out :)
- Please upvote and accept this answer if its useful! : )

While I do know that accepting and/or upvoting an answer is encouraged if you get a helpful answer to your question, as shown in the *[Help Center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers),*

> Decide if the answer is helpful, and then...
> Vote on it (if you have earned the appropriate voting privilege). Vote up answers that are
> helpful and well-researched, and vote down answers that are not. Other users will also vote on answers to your question.
> Accept it. **As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.** <sup>(emphasis my own)</sup>

do we allow comments about people *desperately* recommending/asking for the poster of the question to upvote and accept their answer if possible? I feel that this would flood the site with comments of people desperately trying to gain reputation, and thus led to my question:

- Are comments of people *desperately* asking for people to consider accepting their answer to earn reputation discouraged?
- What should we do when we encounter these type of comments (if we do)?
- If this is discouraged, how should we be flagging these type of comments?

---

<sup>i couldn't find the *exact* comments, so heres [one of the related ones](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/562/how-black-star-was-influenced-by-the-kishins-hallucinations/591#comment743_591), for the record</sup>

Comment: Potential duplicate of [What should we do with questions with answers but still not accepted?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/631/1458)

Comment: @Dimitrimx Oh, thanks. that completely answers my question so it would be reasonable if this was closed as a duplicate